# How to adjust text file saved by python?

Tags: python, arrays, database, txt

I'm trying to save data from an array called `Sevol`. This matrix has 100 rows and 1000 columns, so `len(Sevol[i])` has 1000 elements and `Sevol[0][0]` would be the first element of the first list.

I tried to save this array with the commands

`np.savetxt(path + '/data_Sevol.txt', Sevol[i], delimiter=" ")`

It works fine. However, I would like the file to be organized as an array anyway. For example, currently, the file is being saved like this in Notepad:

[image]

And I would like the data to remain organized, as for example in this file:

[image]

Is there an argument in the `np.savetxt` function or something I can do to better organize the text file?

Comment: Why would it be organized into 3 columns, if your array is 1000x100?

Comment: flags:
+ : Forces to precede result with + or -. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#:~:text=.npz%20archive-,Notes,-Further%20explanation%20of. the shift starts with negative numbers.

Comment: @TimRoberts The second photo is just an example of how I would like to have the spacing. And not to reduce to 3 columns

Comment: Allow me to point out that it's only humans that care about column spacing like that -- the machine doesn't care -- and humans aren't likely to scroll through a 1000x100 table.  Would it be better to create a CSV and bring it into Excel for scrolling?